# is let working as a goto instruction in tail recursion?

Tags: recursion, scheme

I have found the following implementation of the Binary Search in Scheme:

```
(define (binary-search value vector)
  (let helper ((low 0)
               (high (- (vector-length vector) 1)))
    (if (< high low)
        #f
        (let ((middle (quotient (+ low high) 2)))
          (cond ((> (vector-ref vector middle) value)
                 (helper low (- middle 1)))
                ((< (vector-ref vector middle) value)
                 (helper (+ middle 1) high))
                (else middle))))))
```

according to what it says in the comments, the above function uses tail-recursion to call to the help function. I was wondering if this works like a GOTO instruction, because I do not see that there is a proper "recursive" call to the binary-search function.

In this case it is proper to say that works like a goto instruction?

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is called a named `let`. (I wrote a [blog post about how named `let` works](http://dyscour.se/post/58639636506/named-let), if you're curious.) The code you have is exactly the same as:

```
(define (binary-search value vector)
  (define (helper low high)
    (if (< high low)
        #f
        (let ((middle (quotient (+ low high) 2)))
          (cond ((> (vector-ref vector middle) value)
                 (helper low (- middle 1)))
                ((< (vector-ref vector middle) value)
                 (helper (+ middle 1) high))
                (else middle)))))
  (helper 0 (- (vector-length vector) 1)))
```

In other words, it *is* tail-recursing, on `helper` rather than on `binary-search`. But tail recursion is happening.

Some people think of tail-recursion like `goto`, but I don't consider that a helpful comparison. The only thing in common between the two is that you can implement loops with tail recursion, much like you can do with `goto`. But the similarities end there: tail-recursion is a special kind of recursion (where the current call frame is replaced with the tail call), but it's still recursion; `goto` jumps to an arbitrary point in the code, but it's a totally imperative operation with no relation to recursion.

Comment: thanks, so do you mean that the function that is really making the recursion here is the call to the helper function?

Answer (score 0):

A let is just syntactic sugar for lambdas. So for example:

```
(let ((i 2)
      (j 5)
  (* i j))
```

is equivalent to

```
((lambda (i j) (* i j)) 2 5)
```

The let in your code is called a named let, because you provided a label for it. So basically, your lambda in disguise is bound to a name. In that sense, it is a goto. However, you need to be in the scope of the let to be able to "jump" to it. The function is tail recursive because you are not deferring any computations. At any point in time, you only require the current values of i and j to be able to proceed with the computation.